# Formulario nao faz POST

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando inserir o cadastro de um usuário, mas o `POST` não ocorre. Sempre cai na exceção `echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">alert("Erro ao cadastrar!")</script>';`. Abaixo segue meu código, peço que se alguém identificar onde errei, me auxilie.

cadastro.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'php/classes/funcoes.class.php';
    require_once 'php/classes/usuarios.class.php';

    $objFc = new Funcoes();
    $objUs = new Usuarios();

    if (isset($_POST['btnCadastrar'])) {
        if ($objUs->qryInsert($_POST) == 'ok') {
            header('location: cadastro.php');
        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">alert("Erro ao cadastrar!")</script>';
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon.png">
    <title>Sistema</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/helper.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:** -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https:**oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https:**oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="fix-header fix-sidebar">
    <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
            <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" /> </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- Main wrapper  -->
    <div id="main-wrapper">

        <div class="unix-login">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="login-content card">
                            <div class="login-form" id="formulario">
                                <h4>Cadastro</h4>
                                <form name="formCadastro" action="" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required" name="nome" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" name="email" value="" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required="required" name="senha" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" required="required" name="termos" value=""> Aceito os termos e condições de uso
                                    </label>
                                    </div>REVISAR-->
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat m-b-30 m-t-30" name="btnCadastrar" value="Cadastrar">
                                    <div class="register-link m-t-15 text-center">
                                        <p>Possui uma conta? <a href="..\sistema\index.php" target="_blank"> Acessar</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper -->
    <!-- All Jquery -->
    <script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/lib/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <!--Menu sidebar -->
    <script src="js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
    <!--stickey kit -->
    <script src="js/lib/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js"></script>
    <!--Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

usuarios.class.php

```
<?php

require_once 'conexao.class.php';
require_once 'funcoes.class.php';

class Usuarios {
    private $con;
    private $objfunc;
    private $user_id;
    private $user_nome;
    private $user_email;
    private $user_senha;
    private $user_data_cadastro;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->con     = new Conexao();
        $this->objfunc = new Funcoes();
    }

    public function __set($atributo, $valor){
        $this->$atributo = $valor;
    }

    public function __get($atributo){
        return $this->$atributo;
    }

    public function qrySeleciona($dado){
        try {
            $this->user_id = $this->objfunc->base64($dado, 2);
            $cast = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT `user_id`, `user_nome`, `user_senha`, `user_email` FROM `usuarios` WHERE user_id = :idUser;");
            $cast->bindParam(":idUser", $this->id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
            $cast->execute();
            return $cast->fetch();

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            return 'Erro ' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function qrySelect(){
        try {
            $cast = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT `user_id`, `user_nome`, `user_senha`, `user_email` FROM `usuarios`;");          

            $cast->execute();
            return $cast->fetch();
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            return 'Erro '. $ex->getMessage();          
        }
    }

    public function qryInsert($dados){
        try {
            $this->user_nome          = $this->objfunc->tratarCaracter($dados['nome'], 1);
            $this->user_email         = $dados['email'];
            $this->user_senha         = sha1($dados['senha']);
            $this->user_data_cadastro = $this->objfunc->dataAtual(2);
            $cst = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`user_nome`, `user_senha`, `user_email`, `user_data_cadastro`) VALUES (:nome, :senha, :email, :data);");
            $cst->bindParam(":nome", $this->user_nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $cst->bindParam(":email", $this->user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $cst->bindParam(":senha", $this->user_senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $cst->bindParam(":data", $this->user_data_cadastro, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if ($cst->execute()) {
                return 'ok';
            }else{
                return 'erro';
            }

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                return 'Erro ' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function qryUpdate($dados){
        try {
            $this->user_id = $this->objfunc->base64($dados['id'], 2);
            $this->nome    = $this->objfunc->tratarCaracter($dados['nome'], 1);
            $this->email   = $dados['email']; 
            $cst = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("UPDATE `usuarios` SET 'user_nome' = :nome, 'user_email' = :email WHERE 'user_id' = :id;");
            $cst->bindParam(":id", $this->user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $cst->bindParam(":nome", $this->user_nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $cst->bindParam(":email", $this->user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if ($cst->execute()) {
                return 'ok';
            }else{
                return 'erro';
            }

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                return 'Erro ' . $ex->getMessage(); 
        }
    }   

    public function qryDelete($dado){
        try {
            $this->user_id = $this->objfunc->base64($dados['id'], 2);
            $cst = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM 'USUARIOS' WHERE 'user_id' = :id;");
            $cst->bindParam(":id", $this->user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            if ($cst->execute()) {
                return 'ok';
            }else{
                return 'erro';
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            return 'Erro ' . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }   
}   
?>
```

funcoes.class.php

```
<?php

class Funcoes{
    public function tratarCaracter($valor, $tipo){
        switch ($tipo) {
            case 1:
                $rst = utf8_decode($valor);
                break;

            case 2:
                $rst = htmlentities($valor, ent_quotes,"ISO-8859-1");
                break;  

        return $rst;
        }

    }

    function dataAtual($tipo){

        switch ($tipo) {
            case 1:
                $rst = date("Y-m-d");
                break;

            case 2:
                $rst = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
                break;

            case 3:
                $rst = date("d/m/Y");
                break;                  
        }
        return $rst;
    }

    public function base64($vlr, $tipo){
        switch ($tipo) {
            case 1:
                $rst = base64_encode($valor);
                break;

            case 2:
                $rst = base64_decode($valor);
                break;  

        return $rst;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

conexao.class.php

```
<?php
class Conexao {
    //atributo privado
    private $usuario;
    private $senha;
    private $banco;
    private $servidor;
    private static $pdo;

    //construtor
    public function __construct(){
        $this->servidor = "localhost";
        $this->banco    = "sistema";
        $this->usuario  = "root";
        $this->senha    = "";
    }


//conexao
    public function conectar(){
        try {
             if (is_null(self::$pdo)) {
                self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->servidor.";dbname=".$this->banco, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
            }
            return self::$pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                echo $ex->getMessage();

        }   
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Você precisa ver o que `$ex->getMessage();` retorna. Ficará mais fácil identificar o erro.

Comment: E como faço para ver o que ele está retornando? Como exibo seu valor no alert?

Comment: Faz assim: https://ideone.com/DodfPd

Comment: @AndreiCoelho o retorno foi apenas 'ERRO', não diz realmente qual o erro que ocorre.

Comment: Altera `return 'Erro ' . $ex->getMessage();` para `echo 'Erro ' . $ex->getMessage();`

Comment: Infelizmente não mudou nada, continua não me dizendo qual é o erro

Comment: Tente usar o `var_dump($ex->getMessage());`